# real-time web update using WCF

Tags: c#, php, wcf, flash, real-time

I have been reading a lot of forums regarding the use of WCF in web, most specifically, this topic: [WCF with Flash tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306744/wcf-with-flash-tutorial), but I am really confused.

I have an existing feed server that is using WCF service. It is, with no problems, supplying real-time information to its windows applications clients. What i would like to do is to have a web application to subscribe to the feeds that i am supplying to the windows application clients. With the forum that i have read (the one i have indicated), it seems like it will be a request reply method. And i think, using that, i wouldn't be able to achieve the real-time transfer of feeds for it.

I would like to know if there is an equivalent for the callback function in web development.

Answer (score 1):

I think Duplex service meets your requirement.
Please use Duplex type of WCF services.

A duplex service contract is a message exchange pattern in which both endpoints can send messages to the other independently. A duplex service, therefore, can send messages back to the client endpoint, providing event-like behavior. Duplex communication occurs when a client connects to a service and provides the service with a channel on which the service can send messages back to the client. Note that the event-like behavior of duplex services only works within a session.

Links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/a-simple-duplex-service-in-wcf/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731935.aspx

You can also use web sockets which is new in WCF 4.5. Below are web socket WCF links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674271.aspx

Comment: I have been using duplex service. but i need to supply my feeds to a web application. that means, i need a callback-like function that can be used in a web application.

Comment: @mauzinister then use a [callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx)

Comment: i just can't really pinpoint how will i implement callbacks in web applications. plus i intend to use flash. because as i said, i would need a real time display of the real time data that is received from the feed server that i currently have which was developed from C#. i just don't know how.